# c++ input character or check length of string is 1?

Tags: c++, string, character

So I was originally using cin to have the user input a character. Then if this character isn't a, b, or c, it continues to loop and prints an error message. However, if the user enters multiple characters, it prints the error message multiple times. So now I'm using scanf to take in a string and check if the length is 1. This is straight up just not working at all.

```
string enterLetter() {
    string n;
    scanf("%s", &n);
    return n;

}


void main() {
    string ch = "";
    cout << "Type a, b, or c: ";


    while (ch != "a" && ch != "b" && ch != "c"){
        while (ch.length() != 1) {
            ch = enterLetter();
            cout << ch.length();
        }
        ch = tolower((char)ch.c_str());
        cout << "\n" << ch;


    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a string for this? Use a `char`.

Comment: Also, why is your main method of type `void`?

Comment: scanf is for use in conjunction with c style strings, not std::string's.

Comment: why wouldn't main be void? I previously had cin with a char enterLetter() method, but then entering multiple characters would loop through all of them and print the error message multiple times. Also entering something like "fdsa" as chars would break out of the while loop once it got to 'a', and do the same thing as if the user had typed "a" instead of "fdsa". I don't want that.

Comment: `main` should have an `int` type signature. That's part of the language's specs. This is C++, not Java.

Comment: "why wouldn't main be void?" Because [Bjarne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) [said so](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cin.getline()` to read a whole line of user input terminated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

```
char str[64];
cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
```

if the `strlen(str)` is not equal to 1, an error can be thrown. Otherwise, `str[0]` can be compared with `a`, `b` or `c`.

If you `scanf`a string in a loop, it will return the first set of characters terminated by a whitespace (space-bar or new-line char). In the next iteration it will read the next string and so. If a user enters something like `"abc def\n"`, scanf will first return `abc` followed by `def`. If you use cin.getline(), all the characters entered until the newline, i.e. `"abc def"` will be returned in the first call to cin.getline().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, nor should you use a `string` for this. Using a `char` with `scanf` works better.

```
int main() {
  char ch;
  cout << "Type a, b, or c: ";
  scanf("%c", &ch);

  while ((ch > 'C' && ch < 'a') || ch > 'c' || ch < 'A' ) {
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
      ch += ('a' - 'A');
    cout << endl << ch;
    cout << endl << "Enter a, b, or c: ";
    scanf("%c", &ch);
  }
}
```

This uses `scanf` to get a `char ch`. It loops while the `char` is not `a, b, c` or `A, B, C` (as you seemed to want an uppercase use case). If the `char` is uppercase it gets converted to lower case and then outputs the `char`.

Comment: `scanf()` is for C.  `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::string` etc are for C++.  You really shouldn't mix C and C++ together.  `std::cin` works just fine for single-`char` input, using `std::cin >> ch` or `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: I was just going with the suggest scanf. I wouldn't have used it myself but it was in the original question.

Comment: why shouldn't you mix them? scanf is mentinoed here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/ so doesn't it work in c++ too?

Comment: Functions in the `cstdio` header are just C functions wrapped in the `std` namespace in C++.

Comment: It works, but there are generally some downsides. For example, you can call `scanf("%c", &I_am_not_a_char);` and cause very bad things to happen at runtime because the compiler cannot tell what the variable arguments to `scanf` should be (without help). `cin >> I_am_not_a_char` is immune to the program-breaking effects. In addition there are sometimes performance problems synching the C++-style streaming with stdio.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `scanf("%s")` with `std::string` like you are attempting.  `scanf("%s")` expects a pre-allocated `char[]` instead.  If you want to read a `std::string`, use `std::cin.operator>>()` or `std::getline()` instead:

```
char enterLetter() {
    string n;
    do {
        std::getline(std::cin, n);
    }
    while (n.length() != 1);
    return n[0];
}

int main() {
    char ch;
    do {
        std::cout << "Type a, b, or c: ";
        ch = enterLetter();
    }
    while ((ch != 'a') && (ch != 'b') && (ch != 'c'));

    std::cout << ch;

    return 0;
}
```